# SLF4J: multiple SLF4J bindings with Gradle Plugin

Tags: gradle, plugins, log4j2

I know its a common issue to have the issue with SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/<name>/.gradle/caches/4.9/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-api-4.9.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/<name>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.2/afd596adf5086b4f4746254b25a3a4b513f1d6e4/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

I'm getting this error when I run a gradle build and I have applied the gradle-plugin plugin
e.g. class with

```
import org.gradle.api.*
class CommonTestPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
```

and in gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java-gradle-plugin'
```

I'm using that plugin so I can add code to create a plugin.

The error above seems to point to gradle-api as the offending dependency but I when I fired up the dependency-insight task with 
dependencyInsight --dependency gradle-api

it returned:

```
No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':compileClasspath'
```

My question is:  how can I determine how to define/exclude dependency that the plugin is using?  Im using things like the following, I just can't figure out how to apply that to the plugin-api

```
compile (group: 'com.aestasit.infrastructure.sshoogr', name: 'sshoogr', version: '0.9.26'){
    // exclude this to stop warnings about multiple SLF4J bindings.
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Doesn't fit the question as is, but for Googlers like me: you do not need plugin `kotlin-dsl` for _using_ Gradle Kotlin DSL; remove it.

Comment: @Raphael Thank you. It really does deserve a separate question. You save my day(many days)

Answer (score 6):

I've hit the same problem. The workaround I've found so far is a brutal exclusion from the target JAR being built:

```
bootJar{
  exclude('gradle-api-*.jar', 'groovy-*.jar')
}
```

I'm using Spring boot plugin. `bootJar` extends `jar` task.

The question remains, though: do all the users of a plugin must do this kind of exclusion hocus-pocus in order to get it to work?

Comment: Tried this. Still the gradle jar sits in the boot jar.  
 tasks.getting(BootJar::class) {
    exclude("gradle-api-*.jar")
    exclude("'groovy-*.jar")

}